# How to look for two-words id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coffeescript

Right now my app offers certain functionality, which involves browsing through html for specific inputs. Those input have id's which are based on some information user provides. So if in, lets call it `input1`, user gives us "first", we gonna have

```
<input id="first">
```

somewhere in html.

Later on javascript needs to find this input basing only on "first" string, it is fairly easy with jquery and coffeescript:

```
query = "first"

$("#" + query)
```

Works like a charm!
Problems start when `query` is a composed of two words, like "first input". This time unfortunately, code i provided is not going to work. What should i do to improve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`id` values](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) cannot contain a space, so you can't have an `input` with the `id` `"first input"`, it's invalid HTML. That's almost the only rule HTML imposes on `id` values. (CSS [imposes more](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) unless you use escaping.)

Since it's invalid, a browser is free to do what it likes — it could use only the first word and ignore the second, it could use the whole thing, it could throw out the `id` entirely, etc.

In practice, Chrome at least allows the invalid ID, and you can use an attribute selector to match it: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/vulomi/1/)

```
// Don't do this, even if it works in some browsers
var query = "first input";
$("[id='" + query + "']");
```

Note the quotes around the value, you need them because of the space.

But again, those `id` values are **invalid** and browsers are not obligated to handle them correctly. You might consider replacing the spaces with dashes, e.g. `<input id="first-input">`.

Comment: acually its not as bad as you said, tried it also on Firefox and it works

Comment: @Leo: :-) Yes. Probably works in IE as well, but I wouldn't want to rely on it...

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple, use attribute selector:

```
<input id="first second">
```

Javascript:

```
var query = "first second";
alert($("[id='" + query + "']"));
```

working fiddle (updated) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/manassornpn/4h4sLyn8/3/)

Comment: If you're going to have a space in there, you need quotes around the value. They're in your fiddle, but missing from your answer.

Comment: what's the problem with it now? check the updated fiddle. It's exactly what the OP has asked for.

Comment: As I said above: If you're going to have a space in there, you have to have the quotes. They are in your fiddle, but **missing from your answer**.

Comment: Mr Crowder has a point, i tested solution from your fiddle and it works, but your answer is not clear about it, edit it, and i will mark it as correct:)

Comment: my answer is now totally same as my fiddle!

Comment: @AbdulJabbar: Indeed -- and they're both wrong. Yes, it says `[object Object]`, but it's an **empty** jQuery object, because you don't have any elements with the `id` `"query"`.

Comment: [manassorn](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1263158/manassorn) was kind enough to fix it for you.

Answer (score 0):

That problem is caused by jquery naming rule. "`$("#first query")`" cannot be recognised. You can use "_" to replace the space between the words.
Strictly, `$("#first query")` can be recognized, but it gets the tag whose id is first, and tag is "query". Anyway, it hardly can be found.